# Installing Graylog with Nxlog collector on a Windows DC: no service installed

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2019, graylog, nxlog

I'm trying to install a NxLog collector on a Graylog client machine. The Graylog and associated infra (elastic and mongodb) is running just fine.

The install client is a Windows Server 2019 DC ("secondary"/"agent"/"respondent"? the not master new terminology). When I install NxLog, all is fine (the folder with files is created, and the service nxlog uninstalled). When I install Graylog, the "graylog-sidecar" service is installed, but the "graylog-collector-nxlog" service isn't.

The [official docs](https://docs.graylog.org/docs/sidecar#) do not cite which windows services are required at all.

All our other windows machines use the very same installer script and deploy the same two windows services: graylog-sidecar and graylog-collector-nxlog.

Am I doing something wrong? How to install the graylog-collector-nxlog service?